# Creating an image out of raw data in Java

Tags: java, tcp, javax.imageio

I have written a small TCP client to retrieve various data. It works fine for text, but I have no clue how to implement image processing. At the moment, the incoming data is stored in an `ArrayList<String>`:

```
public ArrayList<String> sendSelector(String selector, String host, int port) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

    out.println(encodePercent(selector) + CRLF);

    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList();
    String line;

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals("."))
            break;

        lines.add(line);
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();

    return lines;
}
```

How can I create an `Image` or `BufferedImage` out of a GIF or JPEG stored in an `ArrayList<String>`? (Or am I completely in the dark and have to use different data structures?)

Comment: Are you retrieving a GIF or JPEG file from the server, or is the image data in some other format?

Comment: I get the GIF or JPEG from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open an input stream from the server, create the image using [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29):

```
public BufferedImage sendSelector(String selector, String host, int port) throws IOException {
    socket = new Socket(host, port);
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println(encodePercent(selector) + CRLF);
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        return ImageIO.read(in);
    } finally {
        socket.close(); // closes in and out as well
    }
}
```

For better efficiency, you might wrap `in` in a `BufferedInputStream`.